# llenar input text basado en una seleccion de lista

Tags: jquery

Necesito que si selecciono el elemento 1, el texto "Elemento 1" se añada al input#busqueda, espero de su sabiduría, muchas gracias de antemano :)

```js
   

  var esteLi = $(".datss").html();
  $("#busqueda").val(esteLi);
```

```html
<input id="busqueda" class="miclase" type="text">
<div id="resultado">
<ul id="listas">
<li class="datss">Elemento 1</li>
<li class="datss">Elemento 2</li>
<li class="datss">Elemento 3</li>
<li class="datss">Elemento 4</li>
<li class="datss">Elemento 5</li>
<li class="datss">Elemento 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

va una respuesta super rápida:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.datss').on('click', function(){
    var txtToAppend = $('#busqueda').val() +  $(this).text() + ' - ';
    $('#busqueda').val(txtToAppend);
 });</script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la rapidez, si me sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva este ejemplo bastante sencillo.

```js
$('.datss').click(function() {
  var esteLi = $(this).text();
  $('#busqueda').val(esteLi);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="busqueda" class="miclase" type="text">
<div id="resultado">
  <ul id="listas">
    <li class="datss">Elemento 1</li>
    <li class="datss">Elemento 2</li>
    <li class="datss">Elemento 3</li>
    <li class="datss">Elemento 4</li>
    <li class="datss">Elemento 5</li>
    <li class="datss">Elemento 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias. ya lo he solucionado, este funciona también.

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo lo hago de esta manera con jquery

```js
$('#listas').on('click','li',function(e){  
  $('#busqueda').val($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="busqueda" class="miclase" type="text">
<div id="resultado">
<ul id="listas">
<li id="ele-1">Elemento 1</li>
<li id="ele-2">Elemento 2</li>
<li id="ele-3">Elemento 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: menos texto, misma funcion excelente.